# when formview empty, add row to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I need to insert new record to database if formview mode is empty.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataSQL"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();

**if (FV1.DataItemCount == null)**
{
    string query1 = "INSERT INTO TABLE (R1, R2, R3) VALUES (@R1, @R2, @R3)";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@R1", "TEST1");
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@R2", "TEST2");
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@R3", "TEST3");
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    FV1.DataBind();
}

con.Close();
```

My problem : if (FV1.DataItemCount ...

Comment: You posted incomplete code; it's hard to tell here what is the issue. For example, what is FV1 (looks like a UI data grid or table or something?), and what type of object is DataItemCount? Try to be as descriptive as possible in your question to get help. Does it throw an exception? What is the value of FV1.DataItemCount?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your FV1 is a FormView control and that you want to check whether it is empty (and only then perform an insert operation you should construct your if-statement in the following way:

```
if (FV1.DataItemCount == 0 )
```

FormView's property DateItemCount is defined as follows:

> Gets the number of data items in the data source.

And looks as follows:

```
public int DataItemCount { get; }
```

Which means that when a `FormView` is empty (there are no elements) this property is simply set to 0.